# Which version of oracle thin driver to use with application deployed on Websphere 7.0

Tags: java, web-services, oracle10g, websphere-7, spring-jdbc

I am trying to connect to my 10g database using oracle driver in ojdbc14.jar. My webservice is running on Websphere 7.0 which uses Jre 1.6.

When I am trying to access the Webservice, I am getting the following exception.
**"JDBC driver name  : Oracle JDBC driver

JDBC driver version  : 10.2.0.4.0

JDBC driver specification level  : 10.2

Oracle does not support the use of version 10 of their JDBC driver with the version of the Java runtime
environment that is used by the application server."**

Please let me know which version of oracle thin driver I have to use to connect to my 10g Database using Websphere 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

1. If Oracle 10g ships with a JDBC driver called `ojdbc6.jar`, then you should use it instead of `ojdbc14.jar`.
2. Otherwise, you can use the Oracle 11g JDBC driver (I know, for sure, that it ships with `ojdbc16.jar`). Unless otherwise noted, Oracle's JDBC drivers are backward compatible.

Comment: In all our web applications we are using ojdbc14.jar to connect to 10 g database. I got that working using the same driver by correcting some configuration for JPA in my Web-service. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You said following (in the last line of your original question):

"Please let me know which version of oracle thin driver I have to use to connect to my 10g Database using Websphere 7.0.".

So, please note that you don't have to worry about the version of driver to connect to your database.

That's so because "Oracle 10g Database" is by default shipped with the RIGHT driver to connect to it.

Apart from this, which version of JDK are you using in WebSphere 7 ?

Comment: Websphere 7.0 comes with jre 1.6

Comment: compile .JAR carrying "database driver class" using JRE 1.6 and see is it compiling properly ?